# Update MS Access table using Data from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I just need a logic on how to update an ACCESS db Located at Server1 using data from SQL Server in Server2?
Should I use LinkedServer? Can I do it using C# Console Program? Please advise. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can using C# Console Program and connect to 2 servers.

1. Connect Sql server to get data.
2. Connect Access db to update data.

Comment: More details, please?

Comment: it is logic. if you must detail. please edit your question.

Answer (score 0):

Read [Import or Link to SQL Server Data](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-or-link-to-SQL-Server-data-A5A3B4EB-57B9-45A0-B732-77BC6089B84E)

David